# MySQL sports ranking query for sports with partial results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query like this for a sports ranking page...

```
SELECT
    name AS Team,
    SUM(P) AS P,
    SUM(W) AS W,
    SUM(D) AS D,
    SUM(L) AS L, 
    SUM(F) as F,
    SUM(A) AS A,
    SUM(GD) AS GD,
    SUM(Pts) AS Pts  
FROM ( 
SELECT *,
    team1Id Team,  
    1 P, 
    IF(team1Sets > team2Sets,1,0) W, 
    IF(team1Sets = team2Sets,1,0) D, 
    IF(team1Sets < team2Sets,1,0) L, 
    team1Games F, 
    team2Games A, 
    team1Games-team2Games GD, 
    CASE WHEN team1Sets > team2Sets THEN 3
         WHEN team1Sets = team2Sets THEN 1
         ELSE 0
    END PTS 
FROM ligas_match
WHERE groupId = 1     

UNION ALL 

SELECT *,
   team2Id Team,  
    1, 
     IF(team1Sets < team2Sets,1,0), 
     IF(team1Sets = team2Sets,1,0), 
     IF(team1Sets > team2Sets,1,0), 
     team2Games, 
     team1Games, 
     team2Games-team1Games, 
     CASE WHEN team1Sets < team2Sets THEN 3
         WHEN team1Sets = team2Sets THEN 1
         ELSE 0
     END PTS 
 FROM ligas_match
 WHERE groupId = 1     

) AS tot 
JOIN ligas_team t ON tot.Team=t.id  
GROUP BY Team  
ORDER BY
    SUM(Pts) desc,
    SUM(GD) desc
```

This structure works perfectly for leagues of sports that don´t have partial results like soccer. But I am trying to make it work for a padel tennis league.

In the padel league the matches consist in n sets, the team that wins more sets wins the match and 3 points and if both teams win the same amount of sets the match is considered a draw and they get 1 point each. The sets are also divided in games, who wins more games in a set gains the set (Cannot draw). Now I am storing the sets data (team1Sets, team2Sets, team1Games, team2Games) also inside the matches table and the query works fine.

However, as storing the sets data both in the matches table and in the sets table is redundant I woluld like to store the sets data on another table called ligas_set and do somehow a join between the two tables (ligas_match and ligas_set on ligas_match.id = ligas_set.matchId).

Here is the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/483c7

The desired result set is a ranking table witch each team of the league/group, their played matches P; their wins, W; their Draws, D; their Loses, L; their Games of each set Won, F; their their Games of each set Lost, A; the difference between games won and lost, GD; and their total points, Pts.

Can anyone help on this query?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Sorry, didn´t know about sqlfiddle, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: The scoring is exactly the same as tennis, right?

Comment: Mh, kind of. The number of sets of each league is set in the groups table, Can be 2, can be 3 but always the same number of sets for each league. If on a match of a league of two sets Team A wins one set and Team B wins the other set, the match is a draw and no extra sets are played. A set is won when a team reaches 6 games, and has at least two games of difference agains the other team. If not, they play tie break like in tennis.